# The engine "node" is incompatible with this module error on Borales/action-yarn@3.0.0

Tags: javascript, github-actions, firebase-hosting

good day! I stumbled this error on my Github Action when I tried to deploy my app to Firebase hosting.

Here is the error:
error @achrinza/node-ipc@9.2.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "8 || 10 || 12 || 14 || 16 || 17". Got "18.12.0"

Preview YML

```
name: "Preview Hosting"

"on": pull_request

jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v3.0.0
        with:
          cmd: install  # will run `yarn install` command

      - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v3.0.0
        with:
          cmd: build # will run `yarn build` command

      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0.6-alpha
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_HOSTING_DEPLOY }}"
          projectId: myproject
          expires: 30d
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```

Comment: As the error states, it seems related to the node version. Which one did you configure in your workflow? And which one are you using in your app? (Sharing the workflow implementation in the question could help us reproducing the error and bring more insights as well please).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the version of node you want to use with actions/setup-node. You should also look at updating `achrinza/node-ipc` to a version that supports node.js v18.

```
name: "Preview Hosting"

"on": pull_request

jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v3.0.0
        with:
          cmd: install  # will run `yarn install` command

      - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v3.0.0
        with:
          cmd: build # will run `yarn build` command

      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0.6-alpha
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_HOSTING_DEPLOY }}"
          projectId: myproject
          expires: 30d
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```